# What are the pros and cons of buying a currency etf versus forex?

Tags: etf, foreign-exchange

I want to take a long position in CHF.
Two common ways to do this are with an ETF like FXF, or Forex.

Why might I decide to choose one approach over the other?

Answer (score 2):

A few considerations:

- bid-ask spread
- execution fees/commissions
- trading restrictions
- convenience
- options
- leverage/inverse exposure